# Display flex with justify-content space-between don't works when zooming

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create this kind of progress bar:

[image]

I am doing this by simply creating 5 divs, nested in a display flex `div`.

```css
div {
  width: 42px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div>div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I zoom out the page. The width don't maintain its size:

[image]

I know if I define the outer `div` width to a percentage it works fine, but I need it to be a fixed value. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the browser zoom function is pretty divorced from any CSS code you write - there is no way to account for zoom level or adjust for it in CSS.

You would need to implement a javascript solution to first detect the zoom level, then implement a way to modify your CSS values to account for it. Here is one method for detecting browser zoom level:
https://gist.github.com/kevingessner/5598913

There are a few methods to accomplish this if you search online. I would do research to see what could work best for your use case, but you are going to have to use some javascript no way to do it with pure CSS as far as I know.